# How to get increment num of row in sorted table to use in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join, tree

i just want to find someone can help me.

I have two tables:

first:
id,parent_id,level

second:
id,name

I want to correct sort the datatree by name. Of course i can sort it by (level, parent, name) and next get parent_id associative array to print it in the recursion.

But i can see, what if i'm storing not just level, but delta between relative and absolute level, i can get tree without creating associative array, when sort it in (delta_level, parent_id, id).

Of course we need ID for that! The id determines date_add field. But what if i need sorting by name same method?

First query we sort table2 with autoincrement @num := @num + 1, after that - i need somehow join results to table1.

table1
id,parent_id,delta_level

table2 (sorted by name ASC)
id,name,num

I need to get every table1 row in a view like (`num`,`parent_num`,`delta_level`)

Can someone help?

FIRST EDIT:

```
SET @num1 = 0;
SET @num2 = 0;

SELECT
  t2.`name`,
  t1.`category_id`,
  t1.`path_id`,
  t2.`index`,
  t3.`index` `parent_index`,
  t1.`level` `delta_level`,
  t2.`level` `level`
FROM
  ht_category_path t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    @num1 := @num1 + 1 `index`,
    t1.`category_id`,
    t2.`name`,
    t3.`level`
  FROM
    ht_category t1
  INNER JOIN
    ht_category_description t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id AND t2.language_id = 1
  INNER JOIN
    ht_category_path t3 ON t3.category_id = t1.category_id AND t3.path_id = t1.category_id
  ORDER BY
    t2.`name` ASC
) t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    @num2 := @num2 + 1 `index`,
    t1.`category_id`,
    t2.`name`
  FROM
    ht_category t1
  INNER JOIN
    ht_category_description t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id AND t2.language_id = 1
  ORDER BY
    t2.`name` ASC
) t3 ON t3.category_id = t1.path_id
WHERE
  t1.`level` = 0
ORDER BY
  t3.`index` ASC,
  t2.`level` ASC,
  t2.`index` ASC
```

Given query works fine. Next question - HOW TO OPTIMIZE THAT QUERY AS WELL?